# Plugin.Geolocator exits method (deadlock?)

Tags: xamarin, geolocation

I'm building a Xamarin app and for the geolocation, I'm using the [GeolocatorPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin)

The problem is that once the code wants to get the position, the code exists without warning.

My class fields:

```
private Position position;
private IGeolocator locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
```

My page constructor:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    locator.PositionChanged += Locator_PositionChanged;
    locator.PositionError += Locator_PositionError;
}
```

OnAppearing event is calling the getLocationPermission:

```
    private async Task GetLocationPermission()
    {
        var status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.LocationWhenInUse);
        if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
        {
            //Not granted, request permission
            if (await CrossPermissions.Current.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationaleAsync(Permission.LocationWhenInUse))
            {
                // This is not the actual permission request
                await DisplayAlert("Need your permission", "We need to access your location", "Ok");
            }

            // This is the actual permission request
            var results = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(Permission.LocationWhenInUse);
            if (results.ContainsKey(Permission.LocationWhenInUse))
                status = results[Permission.LocationWhenInUse];
        }
        //Already granted, go on
        if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
        {
            //Granted, get the location
            GetLocation();
            await GetVenues();
            await locator.StartListeningAsync(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30), 500);
        }
        else
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Access to location denied", "We don't have access to your location.", "OK");
        }
    }
```

The permission is granted and gets to the GetLocation() method:

```
    private async void GetLocation()
    {
        //var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
        try
        {
            var myPosition = await locator.GetPositionAsync();
            position = new Position(myPosition.Latitude, myPosition.Longitude);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
        if (position == null)
        {
            //Handle exception
        }
    }
```

Once the line is reached with locator.GetPositionAsync(), it stops. No exception is thrown, also the PositionError isn't raised.

I have no idea why, but in the beginning it worked once, never worked after that.

The location settings in de Android Emulator are as follow:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my research, you did not acheved that `Location Changes` like [this link](https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/GeolocatorPlugin/LocationChanges.html)

I wrote a demo about `Location changes`. This is running screenshot.

[image]

This is my demo
https://github.com/851265601/GeolocationDemo

Comment: Instead of a class locator field, I now get the position from CrossGeoLocator.Current. It now fires two times a position change, but when I change the location, it doesn't fire anymore.

Comment: Did you run my demo?

Comment: Did you add `if (CrossGeolocator.Current.IsListening)
                return;

            await CrossGeolocator.Current.StartListeningAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), 10, true);` in your project

Comment: You can upload your project in github, I can help you to test it.

Comment: @CyclingFreak Are there any updates for this issue? If the reply is helpful, please try to mark it as an answer,  it will help others who have similar issue.